# Array of Object with multidimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

this is my first time using javascript.

I can't insert person into table can anyone help me?
So, I want to make a simple function where I can insert a person into the table, insert name and price into a menu with 2D array and validate if the table full, you cant insert into array of object.

This is my code

```
var d = new Date;
dformat = [d.getMonth() + 1,
    d.getDate(),
    d.getFullYear()
].join('/') + ' ' + [d.getHours(),
    d.getMinutes(),
    d.getSeconds()
].join(':');

function custDine([
    [name, price]
]) {
    this.table = new Array(5);
    this.date = dformat;
    this.menu = new Array(name, price);
}

function addCust([
    [name, price]
]) {
    customer.push(new custDine([
        [name, price]
    ]));
}

addCust([
    ["Pizza", 50000],
    ["max", 60000]
]);
console.log(customer);
```

```
the final output should be like this: 
[
    table,
    time,
    menu: [
        name,
        price
    ], [
        name,
        price
    ], [
        name,
        price
    ]
]
```

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you include the final output. thanks.

Comment: the final output should be 
[
    table,
    time,
    menu: [
        name,
        price
    ], [
        name,
        price
    ], [
        name,
        price
    ]
]

Answer (score 0):

```
  let customer = []
    var d = new Date;
    dformat = [d.getMonth() + 1,
        d.getDate(),
        d.getFullYear()
    ].join('/') + ' ' + [d.getHours(),
        d.getMinutes(),
        d.getSeconds()
    ].join(':');

function custDine(menu) {
    this.table = new Array(5);
    this.date = dformat;
    this.menu = menu;
}

function addCust(items) {
    customer.push(new custDine(items));
}


addCust([
    {"item":"Pizza", "price":50000},
    {"item":"max", "price":60000}
]);
console.log(customer)
```

the final output should be like this:

```
[
    table,
    time,
    menu: [
           {"item":"Pizza", "price":50000},
           {"item":"max", "price":60000}
    ]
]
```

Comment: I tried, but why the menu output is [object], [object]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destructure the `menu` parameter if you want it to be set as `array of array` because you are passing it in the same format to 'addCust':

`addCust([ ["Pizza", 50000], ["max", 60000] ])` <= `Array of array`

```js
var d = new Date;
const dformat = [d.getMonth() + 1,
  d.getDate(),
  d.getFullYear()
].join('/') + ' ' + [d.getHours(),
  d.getMinutes(),
  d.getSeconds()
].join(':');
const customer = [];

function custDine(menu) {
  this.table = new Array(5);
  // this.date = dformat;
  this.time = dformat;
  this.menu = menu;
}

function addCust(menu) {
  customer.push(new custDine(menu));
}

addCust([
  ["Pizza", 50000],
  ["max", 60000]
]);
console.log(customer);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    table,
    time,
    menu: [
      [
        name,
        price
      ],
      [
        name,
        price
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```